# Python 3.X Extract Source Code ONLY when page is done loading

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib

I submit a query on a web page. The query takes several seconds before it is done. Only when it is done does it display an HTML table that I would like to get the information from. Let's say this query takes a maximum of 4 seconds to load. While I would prefer to get the data as soon as it is loaded, it would be acceptable to wait 4 seconds then get the data from the table.

The issue I have is when I make my urlread request, the page hasn't finished loading yet. I tried loading the page, then issuing a sleep command, then loading it again, but that does not work either.

My code is

```
import urllib.request
import time

uf = urllib.request.urlopen(urlname)
time.sleep(3)
uf.decode('UTF-8')
text = uf.read()
print (text)
```

The webpage I am looking at is http://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn=9781111835811 (feel free to ignore the interesting textbook haha)

And I am using Python 3.X on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, I would love to learn how I can improve my questions. This is obviously not a homework problem and I am genuinely stumped. I tried to explain the situation the best I could, and if the answer seems easy and like something I should have known, sorry, I am still learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prices you want are not in the page you're retrieving, so no amount of waiting will make them appear. Instead, the prices are retrieved by a JavaScript *in that page* after it has loaded. The `urllib` module is not a browser, so it won't run that script for you. You'll want to figure out what the URL is for the AJAX request (a quick look at the source code gives a pretty big hint) and retrieve that instead.  It's probably going to be in JSON format so you can just use Python's `json` module to parse it.

Comment: Kindall, thanks for the very quick reply! I have been looking through the source code quite a bit and still can not find the ajax call itself. I have found a js function "fetch_results_cb" but I never see it called anywhere and since I never see it called, I am not sure what to input as a search ID in this particular case. Did you see something I missed?

Comment: Looks like http://bookscouter.com/ajax_prices.php?type=PREFERRED&isbn=1111835810&search_id=mu9trjyA7AfUs works and they're returning HTML. The `search_id` looks like a session ID of some kind; probably best to retrieve the main HTML page first and scrape it out of there (I didn't have any luck with just making up IDs or leaving it out).